# java if nested loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

It gives me following error: The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s)
boolean, int
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

```
package javaproject;

public class NestedIFandIFandElse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int vanus = 50;

        if (vanus == 40) {
            System.out.println("first if ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("first else");

            if (vanus == 50 ∣∣ vanus == 20) {
                System.out.println("second if");
            } else {
                System.out.println("second else");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `∣∣` is weird. Try with `||`

Comment: Fix formatting. what is `∣∣` it is not `||`?

Comment: Looks like `'\u2225'`, mathematical symbol for parallel lines.

Comment: I think this is an important question since those two characters look so darn similar...

Answer (score 7):

You should change `∣∣` to `||`. They look the same, but they aren't:

```
if (vanus == 50 || vanus == 20)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain how you entered that symbol, but `∣∣` is not `||`;

```
if (vanus == 50 || vanus == 20 ) { // <-- The || or works here.
```

I changed it as above, and it compiles here.